# Show the pdf of a chi-squared distribution using python

Tags: chi-squared, python, pdf

I'm trying to reconstruct the pdf of the chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of freedom from a simulated sample. Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

norm = stats.norm(0, 1)

x1 = [x * x for x in np.random.randn(1000)]
x2 = [x * x for x in np.random.randn(1000)]
x3 = [x * x for x in np.random.randn(1000)]

f = x1 + x2 + x3

plt.hist(f, 100)
plt.show()
```

The result I got was this.

[image: Chi distribution with a freedom of 3]

Of course this is wrong. As shown in Wikipedia, the pdf of the chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of freedom should go upwards first from zero and go downwards later, not something keep climbing like mine. Is there anything wrong with my code? The formula I used was as follows:

> Q = x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2

where x1, x2 and x3 are independent, standard normal random variables.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology!  There is a chi distribution which is by definition the positive square root of the chi-square random variable. When you mention a freedom, the correct terminology is degrees of freedom. It looks to me like your code is generating a chi-square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom.

Comment: @MichaelChernick the histogram that was provided does *not* show chi-squared distribution with 3 df, as noticed by OP. The approach is correct and *should* return a correct distribution, but there must be some kind of bug in the code (however i do not see it in the code provided -- but didn't tested it).

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the $\chi^2$ distribution. See the formula at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Searene $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ must be fresh standard normals and not recycled.

Comment: @utobi I have never used Python but I'd imagine each new call to the random number generator should ensure that. Any way, this is checkable by the OP or answerable.

Comment: As the question appears to be "what's the bug?" this belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The '+' operator works differently on Python lists than on Numpy arrays.

```
f = x1 + x2 + x3
```

concatenates three lists into one. However, you want to add the content of the three lists element-wise, which could be done like this:

```
f = np.array(x1) + np.array(x2) + np.array(x3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I tried your code and got the same result as you, if you use your 'norm' variable to generate the random values it seems to work.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

norm = stats.norm(0, 1)

x1 = norm.rvs(size=100000)**2
x2 = norm.rvs(size=100000)**2
x3 = norm.rvs(size=100000)**2

f = x1 + x2 + x3

plt.hist(f, 60, normed=True)

# Plot the theoretical density of f
x = np.arange(0, 30, .05)
plt.plot(x, stats.chi2.pdf(x, df=3), color='r', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

The result I got was

[image: Histogram of Chi2]

Comment: ...this indirectly proves that it is some kind of bug in the code.